# Search SQL database using Java (multiple textfield search)

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I am having a problem getting the results I want from my resultset. I am not sure how to code it. My problem is I have a query that has four question marks that will be provided but textfields entry, but I don't know how to code it...the code is

```
           String descr = desc.getText();
            String mat = matl.getText();
            String siz = size.getText();
            String prod = product.getText();

            String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [Filename], [Path], D.LatestRevisionNo From Documents D INNER JOIN [dbo].[DocumentsInProjects] DP ON DP.DocumentID = D.DocumentID INNER JOIN [dbo].[Projects] P ON DP.ProjectID = P.ProjectID INNER JOIN [dbo].[VariableValue] VV ON VV.DocumentID = D.DocumentID WHERE (VV.variableID = 79 AND VV.ValueText = ?) OR (VV.variableID = 92 AND VV.ValueText = ?) OR (VV.variableID = 328 AND VV.ValueText = ?) OR (VV.variableID = 351 AND VV.ValueText = ?) GROUP BY D.Filename, P.Path, D.LatestRevisionNo HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ValueText) = 4 AND Filename LIKE '%sld%' order by d.filename";
            String host = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AWC_Vault;user=SVC_equivaq_cache;password=NMVBm5a5n7zURnfp0K4y;";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, descr);
            pstmt.setString(2, mat);
            pstmt.setString(3, siz);
            pstmt.setString(4, prod);
            set = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

How do I link the descr,mat,siz,prod to the '?' marks in the sql string and Am I using the PreparedStatement correctly?

Comment: Php is much better for this task

Comment: Your code looks quite correct, is it not working?

Comment: When the button is clicked it doesn't print out any values to the textarea

Comment: Its returning a index 1 is out of range, so are all the others

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your columns types in data base and link your argument with the right method

ex: if mat is int

you have to use

```
pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parsInt(mat));
```

good luck